# Please suggest me possible correction in code (Iphone app development)

Tags: iphone, ios, soap, wsdl, sudzc

I got the following generated code from [sudzC](http://sudzc.com/) and the generated code showing error. I corrected some of errors and now getting in following line of code.

.h file

```
- (SoapRequest*) CreateAdvocacyData: (id) target action: (SEL) action oNode: (nil) oNode;
```

.m file

```
- (SoapRequest*) CreateAdvocacyData: (id) _target action: (SEL) _action oNode: (nil) oNode
        {
        NSMutableArray* _params = [NSMutableArray array];

        [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue: oNode forName: @"oNode"] autorelease]];
        NSString* _envelope = [Soap createEnvelope: @"CreateAdvocacyData" forNamespace: self.namespace withParameters: _params withHeaders: self.headers];
        SoapRequest* _request = [SoapRequest create: _target action: _action service: self soapAction: @"http://www.avectra.com/2005/CreateAdvocacyData" postData: _envelope deserializeTo: nil];
        [_request send];
        return _request;
    }
```

called from other file

```
[service CreateAdvocacyData:self action:@selector(CreateAdvocacyDataHandler:) oNode: [[ alloc] init]];
```

These all are generated code by sudzc.
I have doubt:

- Please suggest me changes in this line of code.
- Please explain meaning of
  `action:@selector(CreateAdvocacyDataHandler:)`
- Can i pass in oNode:nil instead of [[ alloc] init] (error).

Comment: Is this the original code that was generated, or did you already make changes to it? I am wondering for example about the `oNode: (nil) oNode` in your method signatures.

Comment: this is generated code and i changed this to (id) oNode.

Comment: can you post the errors that this throws? and for your question, Please explain meaning of action:@selector(CreateAdvocacyDataHandler:), this calls the method `CreatedAdvocacyDataHandler` while calling the `[service CreateAdvocacy...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some some problems in generated code and I corrected it (form sudzc.com).

```
- (SoapRequest*) CreateAdvocacyData: (id) target action: (SEL) action oNode: (nil) oNode;
```

modified to

```
- (SoapRequest*) CreateAdvocacyData: (id) target action: (SEL) action oNode: (id) oNode;
```

I understood the meaning of SEL (thanks vittal)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html

and I solved the third issue by passing `nil` instead of `[[ alloc]init]`